# Join two tables and get data between date range using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created two tables

1. Item_In
2. Item_Out

with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Item_In
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemId INT,
    ItemCode VARCHAR(40), 
    Name VARCHAR(40),
    Price MONEY,
    Quanity INT, 
    InDate DATE
)

CREATE TABLE Item_Out
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemId INT,
    ItemCode VARCHAR(40), 
    Name VARCHAR(40),
    SellingPrice MONEY,
    Quanity INT, 
    OutDate DATE
)
```

Sample data:

```
insert into Item_In values('0001','C01','LAPTOP','75000','10','2015/05/10')
insert into Item_In values('0002','E01','HD','8000','8','2015/05/10')
insert into Item_In values('0003','MO1','RAM','5000','9','2015/06/10')
insert into Item_In values('0004','W01','MOUSE','250','12','2015/05/10')
insert into Item_In values('0001','C01','LAPTOP','75000','9','2015/06/25')
insert into Item_In values('0001','C01','LAPTOP','75000','8','2015/04/10')
insert into Item_In values('0002','E01','HD','8000','6','2015/08/10')


insert into Item_Out values('0002','E01','HD','8000','2','2015/06/18')
insert into Item_Out values('0001','C01','LAPTOP','75000','2','2015/05/20')
insert into Item_Out values('0002','E01','HD','8000','3','2015/05/11')   
insert into Item_Out values('0003','MO1','RAM','5000','2','2015/06/15')
insert into Item_Out values('0004','W01','MOUSE','250','1','2015/05/16')
insert into Item_Out values('0001','C01','LAPTOP','75000','3','2015/06/29')
insert into Item_Out values('0001','C01','LAPTOP','75000','1','2015/04/19')
```

`ID` is an auto-increment column.

I want to join this two tables and get data between date range, with sum of  `Quantity` and `Balance Quantity`

I hope to get following out put,and I used date range as 2015/04/01 and 2015/06/30. In bellow I typed only two records,

```
ItemId | ItemCode | QuantityIN | QuantityOut | BalanceQuantity
-------+----------+------------+-------------+---------------   
001    |C01       |27          |6            |21
002    |E01       |8           |5            |3
```

I try to do it using bellow code,But it not working as I wish.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Item_In.ItemId, dbo.Item_In.ItemCode, 
    SUM(dbo.Item_In.Quanity) AS Expr2, 
    SUM(dbo.Itenm_Out.Quanity) AS Expr1
FROM   
    dbo.Item_In 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Itenm_Out ON dbo.Item_In.Id = dbo.Itenm_Out.Id
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Item_In.ItemId, dbo.Item_In.ItemCode
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Item_In.ItemId
```

Comment: Can the same item have multiple records on the same date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```js
SELECT max(dbo.Item_In.ItemId) as 'Item_ID', max(dbo.Item_In.ItemCode) as 'Item_Code', SUM(dbo.Item_In.Quanity) AS QtyIn, SUM(dbo.Item_Out.Quanity) AS QtyOut,(SUM(dbo.Item_In.Quanity) - SUM(dbo.Item_Out.Quanity)) as Balance
FROM   dbo.Item_In INNER JOIN dbo.Itenm_Out ON dbo.Item_In.Id = dbo.Itenm_Out.Id
where indate between '2015-04-01' and '2015-06-30' and outdate between '2015/04/01' and '2015/06/30'
GROUP BY dbo.Item_In.ItemId, dbo.Item_In.ItemCode
ORDER BY dbo.Item_In.ItemId
```

Comment: Item Out Table Quantity is wrong,it gives wrong quantity.If you have any idea please comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is harder than it seems.  You need to add up the inventory from the two tables, combining them to avoid duplicates and count everything.  So, the following gives the sum on each date:

```
select ItemId, ItemCode, thedate, sum(inq) as inq, sum(outq) as outq
from ((select i.ItemId, i.ItemCode, i.inDate as thedate, i.Quantity as inq, 0 as outq
       from item_in i
      ) union all
      (select o.ItemId, o.ItemCode, o.inDate as thedate, 0, - o.Quantity
       from item_in i
      )
     ) io;
```

However, your final answer requires cumulative sums.  In SQL Server 2012+, you would do:

```
select ItemId, ItemCode, thedate,
       sum(sum(inq)) over (partition by ItemId order by thedate) as inq, 
       sum(sum(outq)) over (partition by ItemId order by thedate) as outq, 
       (sum(sum(inq)) over (partition by ItemId order by thedate) - 
        sum(sum(outq)) over (partition by ItemId order by thedate)
       ) as balance
from ((select i.ItemId, i.ItemCode, i.inDate as thedate, i.Quantity as inq, 0 as outq
       from item_in i
      ) union all
      (select o.ItemId, o.ItemCode, o.inDate as thedate, 0, o.Quantity
       from item_in i
      )
     ) io;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you would have to take a different approach.

Comment: @sachika . . . The subquery puts the "in" and "out" records into a single result set.  It then aggregates this by day and calculates cumulative sums.  If you want to understand a SQL statement such as this, run it in pieces, starting with the subquery and working out.